# Having multiple window.onload functions in multiple script files

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm building a site and I have loads of scripts going on there, theyre all contained in different files and some of them are onload functions. I know about using a function to run all of them. However this doesn't work so well with multiple files. I've tried using an onload.js file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Site wide funcs
    searchShow();
    // Page specific
    if(getProducts && loadMore){
        getProducts();
        loadMore();
    }
    if(checkBox){
        checkBox();
    }
    if(styleProduct) {
        styleProduct();
    }

}
```

where it should check if the function exists on the page before running it. (Some files are referenced in each file some are site wide and are referenced in the header file)
Could anyone suggest a better option for having all these onload files?

Answer (score 1):

In your script files stick to `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`, as both allow multiple handlers for single event.

**EDIT**

As these two functions are browser specific, it is a good idea to start with some kind of wrapper:

```
function createEvent(objectTarget, eventName, eventHandler)
{
    if (objectTarget.addEventListener)
        objectTarget.addEventListener(eventName,eventHandler,false);
    else if (objectTarget.attachEvent)
        objectTarget.attachEvent('on'+eventName,genericHandler);
}
```

Now use `createEvent` to attach new handler to specific event.

```
createEvent(window, 'load', handler1);
createEvent(window, 'load', handler2);
...
```

Please take into account, that there are more severe differences in event model between browser (such as where is `event` object or `target` vs. `srcElement`).

Comment: Thanks! :) How do I use attach event?